# PHP Mailer - While

Tags: arrays, while-loop, phpmailer, do-while

I'm having a problem when I want to send multi e-mails with PHP-Mailer inside a while.

I've the script that sends the email to 15 of 16 people when I'm doing to the SELECT in muy DB, and getting all the data with an array.

The code:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rangocorreo)){
    //Server settings
    $mail->addAddress($row['correo'], $row['t_name']);  // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject = 'Test';
    $mail->Body    = 'Esto es una mensaje de Prueba';
    $mail->AltBody = '¡Test!';
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = '';
    //$mail->send();
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        //echo 'El mensaje no pudo enviarse. Motivo: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    $mail->ClearAddresses();

    //usleep(500000);
}
```

I tried with different forms of the code, but finally only sends 15 instead of 16. (The e-mail is missing) Just a note, if I do the SELECT in the DB, gives me the 16 emails that I want, so I think the problem is not in the DB or in the query, I think is in this code.

Can you help me?

Kinds Regards.

Comment: Is `$mail->send()` executed 16 times? If so, is it the same e-mail address that fails every time? Have you verified it's a valid address? Have you checked the spam-box of that e-mail address?

Comment: Just an aside - look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer; it’s more efficient than what you’ve written here.

Comment: Finally I change the Mailer to other server, and it works. I think I have some limitation inside my server.